# Array offset error on acces null value in the laravel project

Tags: laravel, php-7.4

```
public function storeonlineclass(Request $request){
            $validator = Validator::make($request->all(),[
            'name' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'mobile' => 'required|numeric|digits:10',
            'course' => 'required|in:Law,Sat,Cat,Business Management,Career Counselling',
            'message' => 'nullable|text',


    ]);
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        $errors = $validator->errors();
        return back()->withErrors($errors)->withInput();

    } else {
        $a = new RegisterReq();
        $a->name = $request->name;
        $a->mobile = $request->mobile;
        $a->email = $request->email;
        $a->courses = $request->course;
        $a->message = $request->message;
        $a->page_type = $request->submit;
        $a->save();
```

In the above code the compiler is throwing error "Trying to access array offset on value of type null".I am wondering why this is comming

Comment: And the error is showing in vender package in location.

Comment: protected function escaped()
    {
        $previous = $this->lexer->getPrevious();
 
        if ($previous['type'] === EmailLexer::S_BACKSLASH
            &&
            $this->lexer->token['type'] !== EmailLexer::GENERIC
        ) {
            return true;
        }
 
        return false;
    }

Comment: try commenting out your validator code to confirm if there is an issue with it

Answer (score 0):

This problem due to your high version PHP. The email validator fails [more info here](https://github.com/egulias/EmailValidator/pull/228).

You can solve this problem by upgrading Laravel from version 5.x to 6 or downgrade your PHP version to what's compatible with your Laravel version.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update version of php in composer.json to ^7.4.1 and it worked. You do no need to update laravel and downgrade php.